# Standard music library interface on android

Tags: android

Is there a standard music library interface (screen and api) on android? I can use the native screen within my app in Iphone. Is there something similar in Android or I need to build my own?

Comment: What is "a standard music library interface"?

Comment: Like the iphone player, you can call the music library inside yours apps, have you seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Android media player. 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html 
**EDIT**

```
Intent viewMediaIntent = new Intent();   
viewMediaIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);   
File file = new File(objectFilePath);   
viewMediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");   
viewMediaIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(viewMediaIntent);
```

Comment: ok, and what about the screen interface? I have to build my own?

Comment: If you want to build your app like a media player - yes, you have to build it on your own. If you just want to play music you can use MediaPlayer class as described in the answer and if you want to play a song or media in the default media player refer to the new edit.